# Interpreting gdb output

Tags: c, linux, gdb

I get a segfault in my program and was trying to detect the source via gdb.

O/p of the gdb is as follows:

```
[Switching to Thread 0xb6dffb70 (LWP 6448)]
#0 0x00adc026 in __strlen_sse2_bsf () from /lib/libc.so/6
#1 0x08049e77 in sim_txn (fd=0x804c5c0) at rand_trace0.c:390
```

and at `rand_trace0.c:390` I have the line

```
system_call_length = strlen("rename(")+strlen(filename1)+strlen(",")+strlen(filename)+strlen(")")+1;
```

Everything seems to be working before it.
I am at a loss.

Comment: What is the value of `filename1`?  (Not the pointer, but the data pointed to by it, up to the terminating `0`.)

Comment: check filename and filename1.  are they valid C strings?

Comment: that line is a mess, why not use sprintf to create the line in a clearer manner, then strlen() the result?

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx ..I agree...things just got added up and landed in a mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are `filename1` and `filename` both valid pointers to null-terminated strings? The most common reason you might get a segfault with that is if your pointer wasn't properly initialized or if one of the strings isn't null-terminated (possibly because of a buffer overflow) and thus is resulting in `strlen()` trying to read past the size of the allocated memory.